# Array inside array, only take incoming array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array structure, this is the array passed in to $response

Array

```
(
    [inbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [location] => 3
                    [ID] => 8ba84195fe79a89af1a4b5bd8c280621
                    [smsc_number] => +44******
                    [sent] => 2013-02-25 14:57:20
                    [coding] => Default GSM alphabet (no compression)
                    [remote_number] => +447****
                    [status] => Read
                    [body] => Yeppp
                )

        )

    [outbox] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [location] => 2
                    [ID] => d22c4368fadd64e98fab64acb6b8fa34
                    [reference_number] => 1
                    [class] => 1
                    [coding] => Default GSM alphabet (no compression)
                    [remote_number] => *****
                    [status] => Sent
                    [body] => Test
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [location] => 0
                    [ID] => f0c05e8dd2578d16d73bf5dbcf2ec3e6
                    [class] => 1
                    [coding] => Default GSM alphabet (no compression)
                    [remote_number] => 0****
                    [status] => UnSent
                    [body] => fdgg ddfgfdg fd
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [location] => 1
                    [ID] => d7537acb1b3994ecc11369bac46c4bb6
                    [class] => 1
                    [coding] => Default GSM alphabet (no compression)
                    [remote_number] => 0****3
                    [status] => UnSent
                    [body] => fdgg ddfgfdg fd
                )

        )

)
```

I'm only interested in the body of the inbox array. I thought I could just do two loops to get this, or just do $response[0] but it doesn't seem to work. Heres what I have:

```
$response = $sms->Get();

foreach ($response[0] as $value) {
    foreach ($response as $value1) {
       echo($value1['body']); 
}

}
```

I'm obviously doing something very stupid - Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: `$response['inbox']` of course instead of `$response[0]`. It's right there: the key for that array is "inbox"! And then `foreach ($value as $value1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach ($response['inbox'] as $inb) {    
   echo($inb['body']); }
```